# How would I make a weapon in Roblox studio

Tags: lua, roblox

So basically I want to make a weapon that flings you and ragdolls you for a few seconds How would I do this?

I already have this

```
local power = 5

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
    
end)
```

I haven't tried anything yet as I don't know how I would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two main functions you may want to consider trying for your weapon:

```lua
local function fling(character)
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    if humanoid then
        humanoid:ChangeState(11)
        local rootPart = character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if rootPart then
            local force = Vector3.new(math.random(-100, 100), math.random(50, 100), math.random(-100, 100))
            rootPart.Velocity = force
        end
    end
end

local function ragdoll(character)
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    local rootpart
    if humanoid then
        humanoid:ChangeState(11)
        rootpart = humanoid.RootPart
    end
    if not rootpart then
        rootpart = character.AssemblyRootPart
    end
    if rootpart then
        rootpart.Velocity = Vector3.new(math.random(-100, 100), math.random(50, 100), math.random(-100, 100)) * 10
    end
end
```

If you are making weapons, use `UserInputService` and `WorldRoot:Raycast` for handling mouse and ray-casting related operations.

For melee weapons I would suggest just sticking to the tool as you are already doing. You can set cooldowns with a `debounce` variable and play animations on activation (depending on whether or not the cooldowns have completed).

```lua
local Animation = Instance.new("Animation")
Animation.AnimationId = "rbxassetid://0" -- My animation ID.

local AnimationTrack = Animator:LoadAnimation(Animation)
AnimationTrack.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Action -- Change the priority.
AnimationTrack:Play(.1) -- .1 Being the time between current animation states & the animation track's initial playing state.
```

There are various ways to implement this, my game uses a cache-based weapon system which stores the guns for later use once they've been equipped once.

Mine is a bit advanced but it gives an example of what you could do with just ray-casting & user input.

https://www.roblox.com/games/9914461012

Comment: Thanks although this isn't really what I was asking, Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Apologies, I just kind of skimmed over your question, though I will add on to my answer.

Comment: Hello I have checked out the fling script it appears it only works on players I just found this out as I was testing it on NPC's How would I fix this?

Comment: The function searches for a Humanoid's RootPart, if you want to fling characters without a root you can get their model's AssemblyRootPart.

Comment: I think that players do have HumanoidRootParts.

Comment: Every character's Humanoid has an associated HumanoidRootPart. If there is no root part, it will find the best replacement in the model.